# Using a empty list as default parameter in __init__, why the list in all instances refer to the same list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
class Entry():
    def __init__(self,l=[]):
        self.list = l


a = Entry()
b = Entry()
a.list.extend([1,2])
assert a.list!=b.list   #assert error
```

if using

```
a = Entry([])
b = Entry([])
a.list.extend([1,2])
assert a.list!=b.list   #right
```

What's the difference between above two examples?

Answer (score 4):

Consult: ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument)

But to solve your problem do this:

```
def __init__(self,l=None):
    self.list = l if l else []
```

alternatively, [as has been suggested by an edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/25557835), (which should have been a comment). you can use `or`:

```
def __init__(self, l=None):
    self.list = l or []
```

Comment: Using def __init__(self,l=list()):  not works

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, but use the second solution I suggested instead then.

Comment: @InbarRose: `l=list()` won't work for the same reason `l=[]` doesn't.  The arguments behave as part of the `def`, not part of the function: they're executed once, when the function is declared.

Comment: Fine, I removed the first solution, just use the second one (the only remaining one). It works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `[]` as default parameter.

Use this:

```
class Entry():
    def __init__(self,l=list()):
        ...
```

Here the problem is that the same list is assigned to each Entry instance.

So what append is something like this:

```
lst = []
a = Entry(lst)
b = Entry(lst)

a.list == b.list # lst == lst -> True
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in the first case, you pass a default argument [ ], which references the same list object.

```
    class Entry():
        def __init__(self,l=[]):
        self.list = l

    a = Entry()
    b = Entry()
    a.list.extend([1,2])
    print a.list, b.list # [1, 2] [1, 2]
    print id(a.list), id(b.list) # 36993344 36993344
```